# Issue with the optional list of label indices to include in the classification report

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am having issues with the `labels` and `target_names` attributes of [`sklearn.metrics.classification_report`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html).

The documentation says:

> - `labels`: array, shape = [n_labels]. Optional list of label indices to include in the report.
> - `target_names`: list of strings. Optional display names matching the labels (same order).

However, in some cases it does not seem to follow what I specify in `labels` and `target_names`.

Example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

y_true = ['default_label', 'LOCATION', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'NAME', 'ID', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'NAME', 'NAME', 'NAME', 'default_label', 'NAME', 'default_label', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label']
y_pred = ['LOCATION', 'LOCATION', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'NAME', 'ID', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'NAME', 'NAME', 'NAME', 'default_label', 'NAME', 'default_label', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'DATE', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label', 'default_label']

lb = LabelBinarizer()
y_true_combined = lb.fit_transform(y_true)
y_pred_combined = lb.transform(y_pred)

tagset = set(lb.classes_) - {'default_label'}
tagset = list(tagset)
tagset = sorted(tagset)
class_indices = {cls: idx for idx, cls in enumerate(lb.classes_)}
labels = [class_indices[cls] for cls in tagset]

print(classification_report(y_true_combined, y_pred_combined, labels = labels, 
                            target_names = tagset))
```

returns:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

       DATE       1.00      1.00      1.00         5
         ID       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
   LOCATION       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
       NAME       1.00      1.00      1.00         5

avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00       295
```

which means the `default_label` label was not ignored (in the support column, the number `295` is much higher than the `5+1+1+5` sum), unlike what I specified.

If I comment the line `tagset = sorted(tagset)`, then I do get the expected classification report where `default_label` label is ignored:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

       DATE       1.00      1.00      1.00         5
   LOCATION       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
       NAME       1.00      1.00      1.00         5
         ID       1.00      1.00      1.00         1

avg / total       0.96      1.00      0.97        12
```

Why?

I use scikit-learn 0.17 with Python 2.7.11 x64.